# Variable Retains Original Value Despite Having New Value Earlier and Further within a Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, async-await, axios

```
let getProjects = function() {
  try {
    return axios.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

let getTasks = function(project) {
  try {
    return axios.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/'+project+'/tasks')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

async function getAsanaData() {
    let projects = await getProjects()
    projects = projects.data.data
    projects.map(async (project) => {
        //project.attachments = []
        let tasks = await getTasks(project.gid)
        if(tasks != undefined){
          tasks = tasks.data.data 
          project.tasks = tasks
          //console.log(projects)
        }
    })
    console.log(projects)
    return projects
}

Promise.try(() => {    
  return getAsanaData();
}).then((result) => {
  //console.log(util.inspect(result, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
  //var asanaData = safeJsonStringify(result);
  //fs.writeFile("thing.json", asanaData);
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

In `getAsanaData()`, `projects` has a new value after `project.tasks = tasks`.

However, it's original value is printed by `console.log(projects)` before `return projects`.

This of course also means that the original value rather than the necessary new value will be returned.

What is the cause and how do I resolve this?

Comment: `Array.map()` returns a new array, it does not modify it in place.

Comment: When are you looking at the log? Since you're updating the object, every time through the loop, and the console contains a live reference to the object, it will change depending on when you expand it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays

Comment: @Barmar The log after project.tasks = tasks indicates that the projects have the tasks arrays added.  The log before return as well as the JSON file that's later written show projects without tasks arrays added.

Comment: @pmkro So now if I set projects = to the new array and then try to return projects, I get nothing but pending promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function getAsanaData() {
    let projects = await getProjects()
    return Promise.all(projects.data.data.map(async (project) => {
        let tasks = await getTasks(project.gid)
        project.tasks = !!tasks ? tasks.data.data : project.tasks            
        return project
    }))
}
```

This will go through the async calls to `getTasks` and return for each the project. Then you should get them all resolved via `Promise.all`